# why Ajax in a web application constructed by Quest OS is not available for external users

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, cross-domain, portforwarding

At this moment, I find a problem about the visibility of asynchronous data in the web content for external users.

1) **With Bridged Adapter in Virtual Box**, Internal Users who are under the network of the same router are able to access to ExPo (a web application constructed by a Quest OS) and Ajax works perfect for them (i.e. **asynchronous data**) with no problem. When I do port forwarding ( starting from Port 80 to Port 3000, starting from Port 8080 to Port 8081)in the router for external users. It is accessible but external users can not see asynchronous data in the web content ( e.g. Live Order Book). **Port 8081 is used for long polling server and Port 3000 is used for ExPo HTTP server.**

2) **With Nat in Virtual Box**, the default setting of port forwarding is:
    **Ajax_forwarding** Port 8081 (Host IP) to Port 8081 (Quest IP)
    **expo** Port 2727 (Host IP) to Port 3000 (Quest IP)
    **Rails_forwarding** Port 3000 (Host IP) to Port 3000 (Quest IP)
    Internal users can access to the web but the data in Live Order Book is not asynchronous and the same for external users (i.e. able to access to the web but have to manually update the content with refreshing).

Therefore, could I consult that whether the problem is **Same Original Policy** or not? As I see ExPo is an online web application, asynchronous data is very important for its usage.